# How to export a cbp file generated by CMAKE?

Tags: c, cmake, makefile, project, codeblocks

I need a cbp file to ship my project(it's a school homework). My Cmake code does it's job well and generates a cbp file. Cbp file can build the project. The problem is that, the generated cbp file is using absolute path for the srcfiles.

When I move the cbp to another directory(like shipping the project) it's still using the absolute path of the original files.

So what should I do to make the cbp file use relative path for the shipping srcfiles?
BTW
I am using Windows, VScode, Cmake(version 3.24.3), GCC(12.1.0) and CodeBlocks(20.03)